# How to translate "weaponize" into Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

The verb "weaponize" means "*adapt for use as a weapon"*.

> "they had produced and **weaponized** many deadly biological agents, including anthrax"

> "this knowledge could be **weaponized** against our own goverment"

In Spanish, we can use "[monetizar](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/monetizarun-verbo-que-amplia-su-significado-1542/)" to convey "convertir un activo en dinero" (turn something into money". What could be used to convey "turn something into a weapon"?

We could obviously say "convertir en un arma", but for this question I'm trying to find a single verb, in the style of "monetizar". I looked into the several meanings or "[armar](https://dle.rae.es/armar?m=form)" in the DLE but it seems that the most widely accepted meaning for this verb would convey something like "to give weapons to somebody" instead of "turn something into a weapon". Bottom line, I don't think that "armar" could do in most of the contexts.

> "They had produced and **weaponized** many deadly biological agents"  <sub>Han producido y **armado** muchos agentes biológicos mortales</sub>

> Well, you know how it is, Mr Fox. You're out at night, looking for kicks, someone's passing around the weaponized hallucinogens... (quote from [Batman Begins](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372784/characters/nm0000151))  <sub>Bueno, ya sabe cómo va la cosa señor Fox, uno sale a divertirse de noche y alguien pasa alucinógenos **armandos**</sub>

> Seven Real Ways the Military Has Attempted to **Weaponize** Animals ([article](https://www.insidehook.com/article/science/seven-real-ways-military-attempted-weaponize-animals))  <sub>Siete maneras en las que los militares han intendado **armar** animales</sub>

What could be a good verb in Spanish to convey "turn something into a weapon".

Comment: The only thing I can think of is "militarizar" but it is not the same.

Comment: El IATE traduce "weaponised" como "adaptado para su uso en conflictos armados" (toma ya), y en el DIRAE no encuentro ningún verbo que encaje, lo más corto que se me ocurre es "adaptar como arma".

Comment: @Obie2.0 it looks pretty close although perhaps not ideal to me, according to the RAE dictionary definition 3, at least for the concept of weaponising anthrax.

Comment: No todo se tiene que traducir en una sola palabra. Que tal **convertir en arma,** "They had produced and weaponized many deadly biological agents" Han producido y convertido en armas muchos agentes biológicos mortales

Comment: @DGaleano Cierto. Esta pregunta cae más en la categoría de "curiosidades" que en la de cosas útiles.

Comment: @Diego Hay "curiosidades" que a veces son bastante útiles :)

Answer (score 3):

Usar como arma.

Ejemplo:Este informe prodria ser usado como arma contra el gobierno.

Ejemplo: Han creado componentes que puede ser usadas como armas biologicas.

Comment: Gracias por la contribución, aunque ya en la propia pregunta yo explicaba `We could obviously say "convertir en un arma", but for this question I'm trying to find a single verb`. Como se dice en los comentarios, esta pregunta cae un poco en la categoría de "ejercicio académico" o curiosidad, y la gracia era buscar un verbo en lugar de usar el mucho más razonable y común "convertir en en/usar somo arma".

Answer (score 1):

Diríamos que en castellano no hay una palabra con la equivalencia exacta de la palabra inglesa `*(to) weaponize*`

El título del artículo citado,

> **Seven Real Ways the Military Has Attempted to Weaponize Animals**

podría traducirse como

> 7 maneras con las que los militares han intentado dotar a animales de armamento bélico

o, quizás también

> **7 intentos militares para la utilización de animales con fines bélicos**